# Famous faces, different ways

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

I'm looking for a two-word phrase. One of the words starts with C and contain eleven letters ;). The other one is up to you to figure out. Good luck!

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
  A C Q
  B   R
  V O M

  R Y A
  B   O
  I L K

  F W P
  D   R
  I U A
 
  V G H
  M   Y
  S C D

  G O J
  L   M
  H I B
 
  R W A
  Q   I
  N U P

  E Y I
  A   L
  M Z N

  L O P
  K   U
  S C T
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Noting that...

> ...each celebrity here is wearing a **cardinal's hat**...

...and we can identify them all as follows:

> **N**as,
>  **N**oel **E**dmonds,
>  **E**minem,
>  **S**am **E**lliott,
>  **S**hakira,
>  **S**erena **W**illiams,
>  **W**ill.i.am,
>  **N**aomi **W**atts

We can immediately notice that...

> ...all of their **initials** are *cardinal directions* (the points on a compass).

Looking now at the letter arrangements below the images...

> If for each grid we take the letter in the same 'compass position' as the cardinal direction of the corresponding celebrity (treating both as lists in the same order), we acquire the letters **C - A - R - D - I - N - A - L** i.e. we spell out the word 'CARDINAL' itself!

So what is the final two-word answer?

> Well, it's possible that the 11-letter word beginning with 'C' is 'cardinality', but since we have deduced the word 'CARDINAL' in its entirety, it makes sense that that one was the one we had to 'figure out'. In which case, making sense of the modified images and the property shared by their initials, the phrase could be **CARDINAL CELEBRITIES**!

The significance of the puzzle's title is also clear:

> 'Different ways' suggests the *different directions* seen on a compass and evident in the celebrities' initials.

Comment: Exactly the phrase I had in mind. Well done! (Again :D)

Comment: Hm, I had figured all of that out, except rot13("pneqvany pryroevgvrf") isn't a two-word phrase I've ever heard before. I guess the puzzle didn't imply that it must be a well-known phrase or anything, just seems like two unrelated words to me, though.

Comment: @SQLnoob I had the same problem - I was even considering phrases like rot13(pneqvany pbbeqvangrf) before I twigged that the intent was probably to 'say what you see'...